# Inline Javascript isn't executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, inline

I want to set the current time to an Element with momentjs.

```
<span onload="$(this).text(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));"></span>
```

What is wrong with it? Nothing is shown.

Comment: `load` events are not triggered on `span` elements.

Comment: The best Answer is a combination of  mattytommo and camus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**onload is not what you need (it won't even work), you need to be executing this on `document.ready`**

I think you're mixing jQuery and JavaScript, try using `document.ready` in a script block.

First we'll give your span an ID

```
<span id="yourSpan"></span>
```

Then we can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#yourSpan").text(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT: As you've said you want it inline (although it's really bad practice and I'll have to wash my hands after writing it), still add your ID to your span as above, but do this:**

```
<body onload="$('#yourSpan').text(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));">
```

Comment: i want it completely inline

Comment: @zoidbergi Is it a limitation that it **has to be** inline? It's really bad practice to do that.

Comment: @zoidbergi Wise choice! :)

Comment: i hope your hands are clean again ;)

Comment: @zoidbergi Nothing a bit of methlyated spirit and bleach can't get rid of :D

Answer (score 6):

onload is not supported in the span tag , some tags that support onload :

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, 
<input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>
```